# IntelliJ : How to maintain classpath order like Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea

I am referring few directories having configuration file and I want to set in the classpath in specific order. We can set order easily in Eclipse as I have highlighted in attached screenshot - [image]

Is there any way to achive the order in IntelliJ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies) documentation:

[image: dependencies order]